# ¿ Como hacer una lista comprimida con dos bucles y una restricción if?

Tags: python, lista, pandas, bucle-for

¿ Como puedo poner este código como una lista comprimida  ?

```
for j in turno:
    
    for trabajador_enfadado in trabajadores_enfadadosEnrique:
        
        if diccionarios_turnos["Enrique"][j] > 0:
            
            prob += lpSum( [variables[trabajador_enfadado][j] + variables["Enrique"][j]] ) == 1
```

Quiero hacer algo como esto:

```
prob += lpSum( [variables[trabajador_enfadado][j] + variables["Enrique"][j]   for j in turno 
                if diccionarios_turnos["Enrique"][j] > 0 for trabajador_enfadado in 
                trabajadores_enfadadosEnrique  ])  == 1
```

Comment: Hola, ¿puedes añadir un ejemplo de los datos que recibe ese fragmento? ¿Y lo que esperas que devuelva? Con solo ese fragmento de código, sin contexto es muy difícil de saber lo que pides.

Comment: He editado la pregunta. Gracias

Comment: Ah!, lo que quieres es una comprensión de lista, ponerlo en formato "corto". Tienes algún `else` para los casos en el que el `if` no se cumpla?

Comment: Hola , no ,solo tengo una restriccion de `if`

Comment: Creo que buscas hacer algo así: [[prob.__add__(lpSum([variables[trabajador_enfadado][j] + variables["Enrique"][j]]) == 1) for trabajador_enfadado in trabajadores_enfadadosEnrique if diccionarios_turnos["Enrique"][j] > 0] for j in turno]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Las expresiones condicionales necesitan un else

Por ejemplo, esto da error: `1 if 'a' == 'a'`.

Tendrías que hacer `1 if 'a' == 'a' else 'b'`.

Por lo que si no tienes un else vas a tener que filtrar la lista en algún momento. Todavía no tengo claro lo que debería hacer tu código, pero quizá algo así te ayude:

Los casos que no cumplen la condición, les pongo `None`, luego el filtro quita los `None` de la lista, que luego podemos pasar a la funcińo `lpSum`.

```py
# Lista sin los que no cumplen la condicion:
lista_filtrada = filter(lambda x: x is not None,
  [ variables[trabajador_enfadado][j] + variables['Enrique'][j] if diccionario_turnos['Enrique'][j] > 0
    else None
      for trabajador_enfadado in trabajadores_enfadadosEnrique
        for j in turno ])

# No entiendo esta parte de tu código, porque es como hacer prob += True (o False).
prob += lpSum(lista_filtrada) == 1
```

No lo he probado, pero creo que el código es más o menos correcto. En cualquier caso, te recomiendo que te plantees si no es mejor dejarlo en varias lineas y varios pasos. Queda más largo, pero es más legible, y eso también es valioso.